# Redirect the login page from HTTP to HTTPS via httpd.conf

Tags: apache, http, ssl, https, apache2

I want my users who type `login.abcde.com` to be redirected to `https://client1.abcde.com` and BLOCK all other HTTP URLs. So if someone types http://client1.abcde.com/thispage/isawesome.html, it will show some error message or a 404. So far I tried to add the following to my httpd.conf, but no success. I keep getting the Apache page saying: `This page is used to test the proper operation of the Apache HTTP server after it has been installed. If you can read this page, it means that the web server installed at this site is working properly, but has not yet been configured.`

> RewriteEngine on
>
> RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
>
> RewriteRule ^client1.abcde.com$ https://client1.abcde.com [L,R=301]

I am using Apache by the way, with WSGI. My virtualhost for port 80 is basically just:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin abisson@abcde.com
DocumentRoot /srv/www/abcde/html

ErrorLog "logs/error_log"
CustomLog "logs/access_log" common

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since no one else has replied yet I will give it a try, it's untested but maybe it will give you some ideas on how to proceed. Maybe this could work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^login\.abcde\.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/$
RewriteRule ^/(.+)$ https://client1.abcde.com/$1 [L,R]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^login\.abcde\.com
RewriteCond ${HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/(.+)$ [F]
```

Also it looks like in your case you have `^client1.abcde.com$` instead of `^login.abcde.com$` in your `RewriteRule`, not sure if changing it will make your solution work.

Maybe you could do the redirect in the `VirtualHost` as described in this [RedirectSSL](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RedirectSSL) wiki page?